# Grails create instance of inner class of service

Tags: grails, grails-controller, grails-services

In Grails, services are singletons by default. Can I keep it that way and still create an instance of an inner class of that service from a controller?

```
//by default grails makes MyTestService a singlton
class MyTestService{

     public class InnerTest{
          String msg;
          def addMsg(String str){
               this.msg=str;
          }
          def printMsg(){
             println this.msg;
         }
     }

}
```

In controller "MyController"...

```
def m=myTestService.getInstance().new InnerTest();
//produces " MyTestService.InnerTest cannot be cast to MyTestService.InnerTest"

 def m=myTestService.new InnerTest();
//No signature of method:MyController.InnerTest()
```

Comment: yep the errors it produces are in the code comments. Is the cannot be cast error due to the singleton nature of the service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do something like:

```
class MyTestService{

     public class InnerTest{
          String msg;
          def addMsg(String str){
               this.msg=str;
          }
          def printMsg(){
             println this.msg;
         }
     }

     def InnerTestFactory() {
        new InnerTest()
     }

}
```

And use it from your controller:

```
def m=myTestService.InnerTestFactory();
```

Comment: still get "No signature of method: MyTestService.InnerTest()"  using the InnerTestFactory approach

Comment: Ok, using InnerTestFactory method, don't use `this` just `new InnerTest()`